# Unable to save player data in a binary file within Update() method

Tags: unity, binary

I'm trying to save player life within a binary file in Application.persistenceDataPath. I've written a method to store the player life:

```
  public void SaveLife()
     {
         BinaryFormatter bf = new BinaryFormatter ();
         FileStream file = File.Open (Application.persistentDataPath + "/playerInfo.dat", FileMode.Open);
         PlayerData data = new PlayerData ();
         data.savedLife = life;
         bf.Serialize (file, data);
         file.Close ();
     }
```

The problem is that when the SaveLife() is called OnApplicationQuit it works. Instead, if I call it within an Update() method of a class, it doesn't work.

The Update() method is called when a certain event is triggered:

```
void Update()
{
    if (life < 20)
    {
        if (//certain event is triggered)
        {
            SaveLife();
        }

        lifeTimer -= Time.deltaTime;
        if (lifeTimer <= 0)
        {
            ResetLife ();
        }
    }

}
```

The container class for the data is

```
[Serializable]
 class PlayerData
 {
     public int savedLife;
 }
```

What could be the problem?

Comment: What do you mean when you say it doesn't work? Is there an error or warning? Have you run a Debug.Log to see if the code is being reached?

Comment: Yes sorry, I wasn't precise. The code is reached both with OnApplicationQuit() than with the Update() method and there are no error or warning. If I exit play mode in Unity and than hit play again, the data are saved only with OnApplicationQuit() and not if i save the within Update()

Comment: Do you have the code for the Update? I'm assuming you're not calling it on every update cycle, as the performance hit on that would be large... are you using a co-routine, or just executing at specific times?

Comment: I'm using it only if an event is triggered.

`void Update()
 {
  if (life < 20)
  {
   if (//certain event is triggered)
   {
    SaveLife ();
   }

   lifeTimer -= Time.deltaTime;
   if (lifeTimer <= 0)
   {
    ResetLife ();
   }
  }

 }`

Comment: Have you tried disabling the OnApplicationQuit code to see if a file is created? I can't see anything immediately wrong with your code, so maybe there's something amiss in the Update script (it might be resetting life too often, for example)

Comment: Put the update code in the main question details.

Comment: @hobnob Yes, the file is initialized when the game start the first time and there are if statement that check if the file exist before to read/write from it. Update() script usually runs SaveLife() within a minute and ResetLife() whitin not less than 5 minutes.

Comment: Is the problem occuring when you check the file exists inside your code? Could it be that you're creating the file, but a file exists check fails because the internal cache hasn't caught up?

Comment: No, the problem occurs either if I check or not

Comment: what is `life` and `lifetimer`? When `certain event is triggered` happens? What does `ResetLife ()` do?

Comment: `life`' is the life of the player, `lifeTimer` is just a timer that start at 20 minutes used to check when to reset the life of the player. `ResetiLife()`set the life of the player to max, reset the timer to 20 minutes.
The event happens when the player dies.

Comment: @RationeUtor Looks like a silly conditional mistake in code. Put the whole script if that's not a problem and reply with @.

Comment: @SP. I solved the problem. It was a stupid beginner error. Just a question since I'm new to this forum. Is it correct to put my solution within the main question or would it be better to answer my own question?

Comment: @RationeUtor No worries. Put your answer in the answer section, how you solved it and why it caused? It may help people who get same issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was caused by another `SaveTime()` method in the same script that was writing to the same file "playerInfo.dat".

```
public void SaveTime()
{
    BinaryFormatter bf = new BinaryFormatter ();
    FileStream file = File.Open (Application.persistentDataPath + "/playerInfo.dat", FileMode.Open);
    PlayerData data = new PlayerData ();
    data.savedTime = DateTime.Now;
    bf.Serialize (file, data);
    file.Close ();
}
```

Since in `SaveTime()` I was instantiating again `Player data`, this seems to cause the old `Player data` created by `Update()` to be substituted.

I solved the problem by instantiating `Player date` only once in the main body of the script.